# How to filter certain records for all database operations in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jdbc

I'm trying to create an API to retrieve records from a database with Spring Boot Data JDBC.

Say I have the following entity:

```java
record Customer(@Id Long id, String name) {}
```

and the following repository:

```java
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> { }
```

Then `customerRepository.findAll()` neatly returns a `List<Customer>` containing all customers, and `repository.findById(23)` successfully finds the customer with id #23, provided that such customer actually exists.

Now the underlying database table has an extra column `isDisabled`, which contains either `0` or `1`. I want my API to exclude all records where the customer is disabled.

I could create queries where I manually exclude those records, like this:

```java
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {

    @Query("""
        SELECT id, name
        FROM Customers
        WHERE id = :id
        AND isDisabled = 0
    """)
    @Override
    public Optional<Customer> findById(@Param("id") String id);
}
```

This works, but the problem is that I have to do this for all database retrieval queries, including `findAll`, `findByName` et cetera.

Is there a way to somehow filter these records *for all* retrieval queries at once?

For example, suppose we have the following table:

| id | name | isDisabled |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice | 0 |
| 2 | Brittany | 1 |
| 3 | Caroline | 0 |
| 4 | Dakota | 0 |

then `findAll()` would return

```
[
    Customer(1, Alice),
    Customer(3, Caroline),
    Customer(4, Dakota)
]
```

Likewise, `findById(2)` would return an empty `Optional`.

Comment: Should be possible by adding a database view that only includes enabled rows… you'd need to add a separate entity for read-only access though.

Comment: @slauth Yeah, but maybe not so trivial. When the view does not include ID 2, one would think that we could add a customer with ID 2, but that would probably break. (In the simple example here, one probably would not try adding a customer with ID 2; but in real life there could be more complex situations where behaviour could become unexpected.)

Comment: @OleV.V. you'd be free to choose which repository to use at any place in the code (i.e. you could still use the existing repository targeting the original table if that's what makes more sense). But of course I generally agree that it increases the complexity.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are trying to implement a 'soft delete' kind of functionality. You can add the following annotation to your entity which will do what you are asking for:

```
@Where(clause = "isDisabled=0")
```

See [this link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-soft-delete) for more information on soft delete.

Comment: That is a Hibernate feature. The OP is asking about Spring Data JDBC.

Comment: @LeeGreiner I do see how this would work, so it's a good suggestion. However, as Jens already mentioned, I use JDBC, and can't get this to work.